# htaccess for custom url routing using thephplegue route

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, url-routing

I am newbie to PHP. I am using league/route from packagist.org for routing in my application and i have a public folder in my root directory where I have an index.php file for routing as shown below.

```
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

$router = new League\Route\RouteCollection;

$router->addRoute('GET', '/acme', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    echo "here";

    return "working";
});

$dispatcher = $router->getDispatcher();

$response = $dispatcher->dispatch('GET', '/acme');

$response->send();
```

The .htaccess file if at the root folder and is as below

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /HMT/public

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

The problem is when i run http://localhost/HMT/acme nothing is displayed. I tried adding an echo statement after each line of the public/index.php file and noted that the line below is the one that does not work. I also think my .htaccess may be the problem??

```
$dispatcher = $router->getDispatcher();
```

Appreciating your help, Thanks.

Comment: You should be getting an error message.Try adding this at the beginning of your index file: `ini_set('display_errors',1);` for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there are a couple of issues here.

It seems as though you have error reporting turned off or you would be seeing some sort of error.

Add the following code to the top of your `index.php`.

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Your `.htaccess` should actually be in your `public` directory and be formatted as below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /HMT/public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !\.(html)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then based on the info you have given, if you access `http://localhost/HMT/public` then all should work correctly.

Depending on any errors you may recieve and the version of `league/route` that you are using there may be one further step to ensure that the request URI is being sent to the dispatcher correctly.

Comment: Thanks. If i access the "/acme" I get the error "Internal Server Error" and when i access "/" i get the error "Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to League\Route\RouteCollection::getDispatcher() must be an instance of Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface, none given."

Comment: Right, this is because your index.php file is set up to use version 1 of league/route but you've actually installed the unfinished version 2